# Images.png Manipulation to SVG in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svg, imagemagick-convert, potrace

iam using Imagemagick & potrace in c# to convert png to pnm and then to svg but unfortunately the SVG File comes with out colour!
how i can solve the colour problem? should i use another converter? suggestions please?

i have tried many packages in visual studio with C# but either don't work or the output comes out with the copyright sentence and that doesn't make my svg file nice!
i want my output with out the copyright sentence please!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Imaging for .NET API. Please open the NuGet package manager, search for "Aspose.Imaging " and install it.
Tip: I am using .net 5.0
The modified code is as follows:

```
using Aspose.Imaging;
using Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Png;
using Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
 
public class Picture
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string templatesFolder = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\"; //the document you want to store
        string dataDir = templatesFolder;
 
        ProcessConvertion();
 
        void ProcessConvertion()
        {
            //Get list of supported formats in
            //Aspose.Imaging for loading and saving images
            var formats = GetAvailableImageFormats();
            var importFormats = formats.Import;
            var exportFormats = formats.Export;
 
            //Process each raster and vector format that can be loaded
            foreach (var format in importFormats)
            {
                string formatExt = format.Key;
                var inputFile = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\1.png"; //your PNG of picture path
 
                //Process each raster and vector format
                //to which we can save imported image
                foreach (var exportFormat in exportFormats)
                {
                    var outputFile = Path.Combine(templatesFolder, $"convert-{formatExt}-to-{exportFormat.Key}.{exportFormat.Key}");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Processing conversion:" + outputFile);
                    //More about load method can be found at
                    //https://apireference.aspose.com/imaging/net/aspose.imaging.image/load/methods/2
                    //Load imported image
                    using (var image = Image.Load(inputFile))
                    {
                        //Obtain default saving options defined for each image
                        ImageOptionsBase exportOptions = exportFormat.Value.Clone();
 
                        //If loaded image is vector, need to specify vector rasterization options 
                        //for export to another vector
                        if (image is VectorImage)
                        {
                            VectorRasterizationOptions rasterizationOptions = format.Value;
                            rasterizationOptions.PageWidth = image.Width;
                            rasterizationOptions.PageHeight = image.Height;
                            exportOptions.VectorRasterizationOptions = rasterizationOptions;
                        }
                        if (Path.GetExtension(outputFile).Equals(".svg"))
                        {
                            image.Save(outputFile, exportOptions);
                        }
                    }
 
                    //File.Delete(outputFile);
                    
                }
                break;
                //System.GC.Collect();
            }
        }
 
        (Dictionary<string, VectorRasterizationOptions> Import, Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase> Export) GetAvailableImageFormats()
        {
 
            ///Raster and vector formats to that we can export images
 
            //Raster image formats that support both - save and load and their default save options
            Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase> rasterFormatsThatSupportExportAndImport = new Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase>()
            {
                { "bmp", new BmpOptions()},
                { "gif", new GifOptions()},
                { "dicom", new DicomOptions()},
                { "jpg", new JpegOptions()},
                { "jpeg", new JpegOptions()},
                { "jpeg2000", new Jpeg2000Options() },
                { "j2k", new Jpeg2000Options { Codec = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Jpeg2000.Jpeg2000Codec.J2K } },
                { "jp2", new Jpeg2000Options { Codec = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Jpeg2000.Jpeg2000Codec.Jp2 }},
                { "png",new PngOptions(){ ColorType = PngColorType.TruecolorWithAlpha} },
                { "apng", new ApngOptions()},
                { "tiff", new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions(Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffExpectedFormat.Default)},
                { "tif", new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions(Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffExpectedFormat.Default)},
                { "tga", new TgaOptions()},
                { "webp", new WebPOptions()},
                { "ico", new IcoOptions()}
            };
 
            //Vector image formats that support both - save and load, their default save options
            //and their rasterization options when exporting to another vector image
            Dictionary<string, (ImageOptionsBase, VectorRasterizationOptions)> vectorFormatsThatSupportExportAndImport
                = new Dictionary<string, (ImageOptionsBase, VectorRasterizationOptions)>()
                {
                { "emf", (new EmfOptions(),new EmfRasterizationOptions()) },
                { "svg", (new SvgOptions(), new SvgRasterizationOptions())},
                { "wmf", (new WmfOptions(), new WmfRasterizationOptions())},
                { "emz", (new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.EmfOptions(){ Compress = true }, new EmfRasterizationOptions())},
                { "wmz", (new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.WmfOptions(){ Compress = true }, new WmfRasterizationOptions())},
                { "svgz", (new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.SvgOptions(){ Compress = true }, new SvgRasterizationOptions())},
            };
 
 
            ///Raster and vector formats from which we can load images
 
            //Formats that can be only saved (supported only save to this formats)
            Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase> formatsOnlyForExport = new Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase>()
            {
                { "psd", new PsdOptions()},
                { "dxf", new DxfOptions(){ TextAsLines = true,ConvertTextBeziers = true} },
                { "pdf", new PdfOptions()},
                { "html", new Html5CanvasOptions()},
            };
 
            //Raster formats that can be only loaded            
            List<string> formatsOnlyForImport = new List<string>()
            {
                "djvu", "dng", "dib"
            };
 
            //Vector formats only for loading and their rasterization options when exporting to another vector format
            Dictionary<string, VectorRasterizationOptions> vectorFormatsOnlyForImport = new Dictionary<string, VectorRasterizationOptions>()
            {
                {"eps", new EpsRasterizationOptions()},
                {"cdr", new CdrRasterizationOptions() },
                {"cmx", new CmxRasterizationOptions() },
                {"otg", new OtgRasterizationOptions() },
                {"odg", new OdgRasterizationOptions() }
            };
 
            //Get total set of formats to what we can export images
            Dictionary<string, ImageOptionsBase> exportFormats = vectorFormatsThatSupportExportAndImport
                .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value.Item1)
                .Union(formatsOnlyForExport)
                .Concat(rasterFormatsThatSupportExportAndImport)
                .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
 
            //Get total set of formats that can be loaded
            Dictionary<string, VectorRasterizationOptions> importFormats = vectorFormatsOnlyForImport
                .Union(formatsOnlyForImport.ToDictionary(s => s, s => new VectorRasterizationOptions()))
                .Union(vectorFormatsThatSupportExportAndImport.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value.Item2))
                .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
 
            return (Import: importFormats, Export: exportFormats);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also refer to the official code: https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net/conversion/png-to-svg/

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately he don't make a real work of vectore! just a wraping the foto in svg format. i dont see a real vectores lines !

Comment: @Sam Sorry for replying to you so late, did you solve your issue?

Comment: I am working on it @wenbingeng-MSFT

Comment: @Sam At present, there are many websites that can convert png to svg, maybe you can realize the conversion on this.